# Finding family of straight lines tangent to $y=x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Knowing that a family of lines pass through reference point $(1,-2)$, and are tangent to parabola $y=x^2$, how do I determine their equations. I knew that eventually I would have to put the equation into the form $ax^2$ + $bx$ + $c$ = 0, so as to acquire the determinant and from that the values satisfying a unique solution, however I did not exactly know how to equate  $y=x^2$ with the equations that i didn't know the general form of.

Original Question: "Find the equation of the straight line(s) which pass through the point (1,−2) and is (are) tangent to the parabola with equation $y = x^2.$"

Comment: Body and title seem to ask different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic (non-vertical) line passing through the point $(1,-2)$ is of the form $y+2=m(x-1)$. On the other hand, the vertical line passing through $(1,-2)$ is given by the equation $x=1$, which is not a tangent to the parabola. So you can assume without loss of generality that the tangent lines you are looking for are of the form $y+2=m(x-1)$.

Now impose the tangent conditions: you want to solve the system
$$
\begin{cases}
y+2=m(x-1) \\
y=x^2
\end{cases}
$$
So plug the second equation in the first one, getting
$$x^2-mx+2+m=0$$
and impose that this equation has only one solution, i.e. $\Delta = m^2-4(m+2)=0$. For the values of $m$ satisfying this equation you get two corresponding tangent lines to your parabola passing through $(1,-2)$.

Comment: So, is there a way of finding the equations of these 2 lines, using only the information already provided?

Comment: Yes sure. Once you know the results for $m$, you just plug them in the equation $y+2=m(x-1)$, and you get your lines.